# Any way to automate Eclipse workspace setup?

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently started setting up a new Eclipse Workspace for a new project I am working on. It requires checking out from a variety of CVS repositories, including setting up a lot of external jars, dependencies, and build paths. Apparently this is relatively common [and long] tasks for new employees or managing code changes and I was wondering if their was some kind of eclipse scripting interface so I can design a script that automates tasks like CVS checkout and set up dependencies?

Comment: Have you considered using Maven in conjunction with Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You can find an overview of Scripting Tools/Plugins in the [eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/Scripting).

To save RampUpTime for new employees you could also:

- `File -> Import -> Install Software Items from File` for a base-setup of plugins.
- Share your perferences with `File -> Import -> Remote Preferences`

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Project set files provided by the team plug ins

Check this http://wiki.eclipse.org/PSF

You can create your own PSF for your workspace and have it set up quickly

cheers,
Saurav

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) project that does exactly this for [WSO2 Products](http://wso2.com/).

The vagrant project is: [here](https://github.com/snowch/carbon-products-development-environment/)

The eclipse application setup script is: [here](https://github.com/snowch/carbon-products-development-environment/blob/2aab91bbde6f2564f1b72f4908e881083519f560/scripts/desktop_setup.sh)

The workspace setup script is: [here](https://github.com/snowch/carbon-products-development-environment/blob/2aab91bbde6f2564f1b72f4908e881083519f560/scripts/developer_setup.sh)

Currently, it imports all the projects, but doesn't yet build the workspace automatically - that is my next goal.

---

Credits:

Kudos to [spektom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398309/spektom) and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11435911/1033422) that made it all possible.